# Category Slugs = 404s?

Tags: slug

With the help of the internet and you lot, I have been stumbling about to create a worpress site [here](http://www.dekho.com.au).

So at this stage, its not exactly a default install.
- Im running the boldy theme from Site5.
- Have made some tweaks to the underlying PHP, but nothing that I can think that would cause this issue.

**Issue**:
Slugs setup normally for categories:

[image]

But the URL it takes me too is a 404.

> http://www.dekho.com.au/category/screencasts/

All my categories are broken, except my [case studies category](http://www.dekho.com.au/category/case-studies/).
- This uses a Portfolio template to display posts in that category (part of Boldy theme)

Im sure I had both the 'portfolio' and the other category links working at the same time.

**What have I missed?**

Comment: It's not actually taking you to a 404 page or showing a 404 error.  It's using the content after the else statement in your template because it thinks there are no posts in the category.  Can you add the final version of index.php you went with (from the last question).

Comment: I see. There are 11 posts in the category screencasts.
Functions as it stands now:  http://www.dekho.com.au/Functions.txt

Comment: functions.php is fine what about index.php?

Comment: http://www.dekho.com.au/index.txt

Comment: It's not using that template.  Do you have an archive.php in your theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think is causing the problem:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-98, 101, 102'); ?>
```

should be:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-98,-101,-102'); ?>
```

The way it is now, it's telling WordPress re-run the old query, but give me nothing from category 98, AND only pull posts from categories 101 and 102. I'm guessing you want it to be re-running the original query, leaving out 98, 101, and 102.

Comment: An easy way to check if this is really the problem is to comment that line out and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Correct!  I should really have picked this one up myself, or at least with a bit of trial and error reverting to backups, seen what change caused this.  Thanks loads John.

Comment: Happy to help! I know it helps me to have a second pair of eyes on really tough bugs. :)